# Keyboard, wifi and bluetooth not working

Tags: boot, dual-boot, wireless, keyboard, bios

I ran into this rather interesting problem this morning: when booting up my laptop (HP Zbook 15 G3), my (built-in) keyboard, wifi and bluetooth all stopped working. I use ubuntu 18.04.

In settings, the wi-fi tab states: "no wi-fi adapter found", similar for bluetooth.

Also, my keyboard is not working already when booting up, that is, I cannot press esc to go into bios.

My usb mouse, and my built-in touchpad are still working. Also, my keyboard backlight still functions when typing.

I noticed all this when booting up my laptop this morning.

I have no clue where to start looking for fixes to this problem. Do you have suggestions?

P.S. Apologies for bad formatting, doing this via phone for obvious reasons.

Comment: My understanding is that you cannot use your build-in keyboard at all ? What about a Keyboard you would plug with USB ? OR it is just in the first times of booting ?

If it works (with external keyboard or later with the buildin one), can you go in tty3 (<kbd> Ctrl + Alt + F3</kbd>), login, and edit your question with the returns of `uname -a ; lspci -k ; cat /proc/bus/input/devices` ; optionnaly, I do not think it's relevant, what about `lsusb` ?

Comment: I could not use my built-in keyboard at all. I did not have a USB keyboard at my home, so I was using the on-screen keyboard to type. Although I'm not sure what the problem was, it has been solved through thoroughly shutting down my laptop. Feel quite stupid now.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is solved. Luckily it was easier than I thought.

Although rebooting the laptop didn't work on it's own, removing the battery whilst powered off, and then booting up again with the battery back in has solved all problem.